# no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Tags: kubernetes

my pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database-disk
  labels:
    stage: production
    name: database
    app: mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

when i ran `kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml` i got the following error 
`Normal  FailedBinding  12h (x83 over 13h)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set`

same pvc worked fine on "GKE" (Google Kubernetes Engine) but failing in my local cluster using [microk8s](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you create any PV in your cluster?

PV and Storage classes on local clusters should be done manually by cluster admin.

Check out [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) for the details:

> 1. A cluster administrator creates a PersistentVolume that is backed by physical storage. The administrator does not associate the volume
>      with any Pod.
> 2. A cluster user creates a PersistentVolumeClaim, which gets automatically bound to a suitable PersistentVolume.
> 3. The user creates a Pod that uses the PersistentVolumeClaim as storage.

Comment: The doc mentions it requires a cluster with ONLY one node. What if my cluster has more than 1 node?