# kubernetes dynamic pv with aws is in pending

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, amazon-eks

I am creating redis-cluster on kube with aws-gp2 persistent volume. I was using [redis-cluster.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanderploegsma/redis-cluster/master/redis-cluster.yml)

I have created Storage Class according to this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/), for dynamic persistence volume creation

This is my StorageClass definition

```
    kind: StorageClass
    apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: aws-gp2
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
    parameters:
      type: gp2
      zones: us-west-2a, us-west-2b, us-west-2c
      fsType: ext4
    reclaimPolicy: Retain
    allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

When I try to create cluster volume creation stuck at `pending` state, after checking logs found this

```
  $ kubectl -n staging describe pvc data-redis-cluster-0
  Name:          data-redis-cluster-0
  Namespace:     staging
  StorageClass:
  Status:        Pending
  Volume:
  Labels:        app=redis-cluster
  Annotations:   <none>
  Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
  Capacity:
  Access Modes:
  Events:
    Type    Reason         Age                From                         Message
    ----    ------         ----               ----                         -------
    Normal  FailedBinding  13s (x11 over 2m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

and events

```
    $ kubectl -n staging get events
    LAST SEEN   FIRST SEEN   COUNT     NAME                                    KIND                    SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON             SOURCE                        MESSAGE
    10s         10s          1         redis-cluster.15816c6dc1d6c03a          StatefulSet                         Normal    SuccessfulCreate   statefulset-controller        create Claim data-redis-cluster-0 Pod redis-cluster-0 in StatefulSet redis-cluster success
    10s         10s          1         redis-cluster.15816c6dc2226fe0          StatefulSet                         Normal    SuccessfulCreate   statefulset-controller        create Pod redis-cluster-0 in StatefulSet redis-cluster successful
    8s          10s          3         data-redis-cluster-0.15816c6dc1dfd0cb   PersistentVolumeClaim               Normal    FailedBinding      persistentvolume-controller   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
    3s          10s          5         redis-cluster-0.15816c6dc229258d        Pod                                 Warning   FailedScheduling   default-scheduler             pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 4 times)
```

someone point out what is wrong here ?

Comment: Since it's EKS, you'll have to ask Amazon support, since you have no access to the controller-manager Pods that one would normally use to troubleshoot such a mess.

Comment: possibly same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230375/no-persistent-volumes-available-for-this-claim-and-no-storage-class-is-set

Comment: Nope, I am having issue with dynamically creating PV. Manual PV and PVC creation works.

Answer (score 3):

Since cluster doesn't have default `StorageClass`, I had to add `storageClassName: aws-gp2` to `volumeClaimTemplates`, which helped me to fix this issue

like this

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      namespace: staging
      name: data
      labels:
        name: redis-cluster
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: aws-gp2
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
```

Comment: The storage class was just named 'gp2' in my case