# kubernetes local storage - no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to set up a mongodb replicaset using this guide: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/
I want my data to be stored locally for the replicaset following https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/.

The pod status stays `PENDING` because of the following event:

```
Normal     FailedBinding  3m47s (x723 over 3h3m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

However I declared my storage class and persistent volumes (unlike [no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230375/no-persistent-volumes-available-for-this-claim-and-no-storage-class-is-set)).

Here is the deployment file:

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-pv-kworker1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/vagrant/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kworker1.example.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-pv-kworker2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/vagrant/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kworker2.example.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo,environment=test"
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: local-storage
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Those outputs may be useful:

```
$ kubectl describe sc
Name:            local-storage
IsDefaultClass:  No
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"local-storage"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/no-provisioner","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}

Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
Parameters:            <none>
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     WaitForFirstConsumer
Events:                <none>
```

---

```
$ kubectl describe pv
Name:              local-pv-kworker1
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"local-pv-kworker1"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnc...
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      local-storage
Status:            Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          3Gi
Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        kubernetes.io/hostname in [kworker1.example.com]
Message:
Source:
    Type:  LocalVolume (a persistent volume backed by local storage on a node)
    Path:  /home/vagrant/data
Events:    <none>


Name:              local-pv-kworker2
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"local-pv-kworker2"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnc...
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      local-storage
Status:            Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          3Gi
Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        kubernetes.io/hostname in [kworker2.example.com]
Message:
Source:
    Type:  LocalVolume (a persistent volume backed by local storage on a node)
    Path:  /home/vagrant/data
Events:    <none>
```

---

```
$ kubectl describe pvc
Name:          mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        environment=test
               role=mongo
Annotations:   storageClassName: local-storage
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type       Reason         Age                      From                         Message
  ----       ------         ----                     ----                         -------
  Normal     FailedBinding  2m36s (x783 over 3h17m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
Mounted By:  mongo-0
```

Comment: Hi, Perhaps PVC and PV are not bound yet due to the scheduler, can you check the events related to the pod. `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME` https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local

Comment: Or can you try to have same capacity in the PVC and PV `Capacity:          3Gi`

Comment: Indeed there is something here: `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME` : `Warning  FailedScheduling  4m41s (x99 over 69m)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`

Comment: Thus, its kind of deadlock problem as storage class delay volume binding until pod scheduling, schluder is waiting for binding between pvc and pv.

Comment: Any hints to solve this ?

Comment: I would love to see whole sequence of events, could you add them here please ?

Comment: @charlycou can you provide whole flow and steps you have followed and events ?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ? If yes, could you please provide events of the pod.
        You can get events of that particular pod by the following command 
    
      **kubectl get events --all-namespaces | grep -i $podname**

Comment: In my case I had not set `storageClassName` on the PersistentVolume (as the error indicates).